# Library not found for -lXXX

Tags: iphone, xcode

If your trying to run an iphone project downloaded from the internet in Xcode and you encounter "Library not found for -lxxx", where -xxx is some third party library where would you look to set the library path? I am not sure where this is setup, in the SCM->library path is blank and everything else seems to match the configuration window for other working projects

When I look at the build log i see the following in the linker output:

-ObjC -ljson

How can i configure the project to not try to link in that library at build time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the build tab of project settings there is a field for linker options, I removed the -ljson from here to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

if using `cocoapods` and getting this error, try updating the `cococapods`
`$ sudo gem update cocoapods`
 Then update the pod for the project
`$ pod update`
I don't know the exact reason but I think it was because the old version didn't set the libraries properly for the new `XCode`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm I was getting this error in xcode 5: ld: library not found for -lPods and following the above fixed it. Thanks Nate:)

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to add that library to add your project or you can remove from the project and delete all the reference.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483909/how-should-i-manage-dependencies-across-projects-in-an-xcode-workspace) may help you, just click on the library and change the 'required' option.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful in some cases:

```
Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Locations > Advanced, select Unique.
```

I was facing a similar issue and chaging to "unique" from "legacy" solved the problem