# Adding an xcode project into another xcode project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I came across many other SO question but could not found the answer what i needed.

So heres my problem.

I have created a simple app that just shows the google map and shows my current location.

and then I have created another `TabBar` based application.
Now how I will include that map application to my new `TabBar` based application.
And when I select the tab the map project should show its data.
means the map should be shown.

How this could be achieved??

Comment: so by creating a workspace i will be able to add the map project, i have to then use the same normal procedure to load the tab..that we do in an appllication

Comment: what to do after i create a new workspace??

Comment: If you meant to ask robin, you need to reply to robin's post.

Comment: @user523234 the above were asked before he posted his answer..:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create a Workspace if you want to manage code base for 2 projects sharing same resources.

Here are some links that will help you get to know how xcode workspace works.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

[How should I manage dependencies across projects in an Xcode workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483909/how-should-i-manage-dependencies-across-projects-in-an-xcode-workspace)

http://blog.harbinger-systems.com/2011/11/workspace-%E2%80%93-better-way-of-organizing-your-xcode-projects/

http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/06/library-management-with-xcode-workspaces.html

You might or might not get much help from the last link but it will be of a great assest for you to learn the library management from workspace.