# How to share files between two xcode projects in workspace?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-targets

I learnt about Xcode workspace .I know how to share the static library but i want to share the files between two xcode projects in workspace and is it possible to run multiple targets at a time?Can you provide me the information of how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

Sharing files between projects in the same workspace is easy, even if the projects are on the same level (no subprojects):

Assume you want to share constants between `Project1` and `Project2`, and these constants are defined in a file `SharedConstants.swift`, which is defined in `Project1`.
In order to be used in `Project2`, it must be compiled there.

Thus, activate in the project navigator `Project2`, select the target and open the `Build Phases` tab.
Open there `Compile Sources` by tapping the little triangle left.

Tap the `+` button below the listed sources for this target. This will show you a list of files of `Project2`. There you cannot select your shared constants, because they do not belong to this project.
However left bottom is a button `Add other…`
Tapping it will open a standard file selection window where you can select `SharedConstants.swift` from `Project1`.

After tapping `Open`, a 2nd window opens with a `Destination: Copy items if needed` checkbox.

**Important: Do not check this box!**

If you would check it, a **copy** of `SharedConstants.swift` would be used in `Project2`, and any changes that you make in `Project1` would not be visible in `Project2`. Instead, it you uncheck it, only a **reference** to `SharedConstants.swift` in `Project1` would be used in `Project2`, and any changes will affect both projects.

Comment: You can also drag an entire directory into your project. 
When you are prompted as in the above example leave "copy ..." unchecked, and for add folders: select "create groups".

Answer (score 0):

To share the files you can probably use the [bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html)

Targets are manipulated with [Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH8-SW1) in Xcode 4, you can launch several targets in the same time if you select the different destinations (with OS X you can probably have the same destination :) )

You'll see a little triangle below the stop button indicating that you can long-press it to select which operation should be terminated:[image: Xcode]

You can switch the console with the popover at the Debug area where you see the target name and icon - that's a button.

Comment: I'm not understanding how to share files using bundles

Comment: @Shreya P Like the library, create the bundle once and add it to any project resources like you do it for images and audio files.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag Xcode projects into other Xcode projects to nest them.

More info here:

[How should I manage dependencies across projects in an Xcode workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483909/how-should-i-manage-dependencies-across-projects-in-an-xcode-workspace)