# Can i run multiple target at a time in xcode?

Tags: xcode

Can any one help me, i am using  multiple projects in workspace, so i want to run multiple targets at a time, how to add multiple targets and run it? how to do that. please let me know.

Comment: Did you see thi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947133/how-to-share-files-between-two-xcode-projects-in-workspace ??

Answer (score 0):

Select the scheme for the target you want to run and run it,