# Xcode Target/Project Organization Best Practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, visual-studio

Coming from a Visual Studio background, I am finding it difficult to grok how Apple wants me to use Xcode to build larger projects. Perhaps it is my fault for trying to apply Visual Studio semantics but I'm curious how one should organize a "solution" that look something like this.

```
MySolution
-Library1 (output: DLL, configurations: Debug/Release)
-Library2 (output: DLL, configurations: Debug/Release)
-Application1 (output: EXE, configurations: Debug/Release, references Library1 and Library2)
```

How does this transplant into Xcode parlance w/ targets? Should each of these components be their own project inside a single workspace or all jammed in together into a single project with multiple targets?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I manage dependencies across projects in an Xcode workspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5483909/2596334) ?